# What is this SIGSEGV error code 14?

Tags: redhat, segmentation-fault, linux

Every day this error occured

```
 kernel: crond[1234]: segfault at xxxxxxx rip xxxx rsp xxx error 14
```

What's happen

Answer (score 1):

It's the [fault reason](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/mm/fault.c#l19).

Comment: Thank you for answering .  What is error 14? Could you describe details?

Comment: It's a user-mode instruction fetch where the pointer used the reserved bit of the selector.

Comment: link leads to newer source code; maybe this fits better: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.39.4/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c

Answer (score 1):

I got this message with this [tool](https://rgeissert.blogspot.ca/p/segmentation-fault-error.html) : "error 14: The cause was a user-mode write resulting in no page being found. A reserved bit was detected."